Lua + VLC Media Player: Error when trying to edit the "vlcrc" file from VLC Lua Extension
Basically, I am trying to edit the vlcrc file(%APPDATA%\vlc\vlcrc) from within the VLC > View > Edit the path for saving recordings menu item by running the below extension code file:
function descriptor()
  return {
    title = "VLC Edit Record Dir";
    version = "0.0.1";
    author = "vicky-dev";
    shortdesc = "&Edit the path for saving recordings";
  }
end

function main_fn()
  local id = vlc.playlist.current()
  local item = (vlc.player or vlc.input).item()
  local uri = item:uri()
  vlc.msg.dbg("[VLC Playing] Write File!")
  local fname_tmp = item:uri():match("([^/\\]*)$")
  local file_name = vlc.strings.decode_uri(fname_tmp)
  write_file(vlc.config.userdatadir().."\n")
  edit_vlcrc_file(file_name)
end

function activate()
  main_fn()
end

function deactivate()
  vlc.deactivate()
end

function close()
  deactivate()
end

function write_file(data)
  local file = vlc.config.userdatadir() .. "/VLC_Current_Playing.txt"
  assert(os.remove(file))
  vlc.msg.dbg("[VLC Playing] Write File!")
  local VLCPlayingFile = vlc.config.userdatadir() .. "/VLC_Current_Playing.txt"
  local file = io.open(VLCPlayingFile, "a+")
  file:write('Current Media File: '..data)
  file:close()
end

function edit_vlcrc_file(videoName)
  local vlcRc = vlc.config.userdatadir() .. "\\vlcrc"
  write_file(vlcRc)
  local file = io.open(vlcRc, "w+")
  for line in io.lines(file) do
    line:gsub("input-record-path*", "input-record-path=C:\Users\<Username>\Videos\<CustomFolder>".."\\"..videoName)
  end
  -- file:write('Current Media File: '..data)
  file:close()
end


Notice that I am getting the path of vlcrc file correctly, as you can see in the text file that I have made for debug purpose using write_file() method.
But the code when trying to open vlcrc file for write mode (w+), it throws this error:
<codefile>.lua:47: bad argument #1 to 'lines' (string expected, got userdata)

Can anyone help out in understanding why it's throwing that error on for line in io.lines(file) do and fixing it therein ?

io.lines is expecting a string (a path to a file) and you are passing it userdata object (the object returned from file.open). Just pass the path directly to io.lines without using file.open

^ just noticed I wrote file.open instead of io.open but its the same point anyway. Just use io.lines with the path
